# how to create sub events in full calendar?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

I have a question about how I could add sub events at a specific time this way.
[image]

What path could I take to solve this?
First of all, Thanks.

Comment: Events may overlap each other on the calendar. What have you researched or tried so far to attempt to solve this yourself?

Comment: what I have tried is to insert html in the container of the event, in this way: 

element.find('.fc-content').append("<div id='lunch_"+i+"' class='fc-event-lunch' style="width:100%; height:"+lonch_hours_height+"px; margin-top:"+top+"px'>" +"<span>Lunch </span></div>"); 

the variable "top" is the one that defines the top with respect to the beginning of the event in pixels. It works well if the event does not happen the next day, otherwise everything goes haywire.

Comment: It will be hard since you never know the height of the event and can't relate it to a specific time on the calendar grid. Instead I suggest you provide this information as a separate event object which can overlap with your main event. Or, split your main event into two parts (before lunch and after lunch). Depends on how it best fits your data and business requirements.

Comment: my business requirements tell me that I should not split the event, maybe I could insert another event within the main event, that is, a main event that contains a lunch event at a certain time

Comment: yes that's the other alternative I suggested - put in another event which overlaps it. You can also control the appearance in that situation using https://fullcalendar.io/docs/agenda/slotEventOverlap/

Comment: ok, i'm going to try it thank you very much @ADyson